# Detect "change of step" between rows in a db column using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in MySQL table that has nearly equal interval between row's values (type is datetime). At some point, this interval becomes much much smaller and remains small till the end of table. I need to get a value of a cell that corresponds to this sudden jump in interval.

Of course I can download the whole thing, scan through values and detect the stepping change, but this application is web-based and I would like to avoid unnecessary load. Can I detect the value at which sudden change of stepping happens, by purely MySQL means?

Example:

```
# step is 1 month for some rows...
1960.01.01 00:00:00
1960.02.01 00:00:00
1960.03.01 00:00:00 <- at this point, step changes to just 1 hour
1960.03.01 01:00:00 
1960.03.01 02:00:00
1960.03.01 03:00:00
```

I need a query that returns me the value of "1960.03.01 00:00:00", the point where stepping suddently changed.

Thanks in advance, Askar

Comment: Show sample input and desired output.

Comment: Yes, using a self `JOIN`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek post updated with example.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO could you maybe make an example?

Comment: LEAD or LAG function in Oracle - maybe helps your search

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             (select MIN(t.dt) from t t2 where t2.dt > t.dt
             ) as nexttime,
             (select MAX(t.dt) from t t2 where t2.dt < t.dt
             ) as prevtime
      from t
     ) t
where to_seconds(t.dt) - to_seconds(t.prevtime) <> to_seconds(t.nexttime) - to_seconds(t.dt)
```

The subquery calculates the largest time before (`prevtime`) and the first time after (`nexttime`) using correlated subqueries.  It then checks the time difference for each row between the previous time and the next time.  When the difference (in seconds) is different, the row is chosen.

If you have an index on the `datetime` column, it should perform well.

Comment: thanks for explanation! Though when I tried to apply it to my table, I got some errors. Could you maybe explain LOGIC behind your query so I look into how I could adjust it in order to work?